# How to Create a Profile Visit Ad on Instagram using Ads Manager?

Tags: facebook, landing-page, instagram

I have already created a profile visit Ad using Ads Manager. Here is the objective for the campaign, I have selected **Leads** and in the Ad set level I have selected **website** as the conversion type. My performance Goal is **Maximise number of Landing Page views**. Here I have used my **Instagram page as a landing Page**. The call to action used is "**Subscribe Now**" as Ads Manager only has selected call to action buttons. The problem is I am getting Fewer profile Visits and a very low increase in Followers using this method.

I run similar Ads using Meta Business Suite. Where there is an objective called more Profile visits and I get a good result on Profile visits and very good growth in followers.

What changes I can do in the Ads Manager to get the same results just like when I run my Ads using Meta Business Suite?